# IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds, Machine Learning Classification

Tags: python, pandas, classification

I'm trying to do machine learning classification with a leave-one-out Cross-Validation. This is the first part of the code.

```
listOfRows = []
dfModelPerf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['threshold', 'c', 'class_weights', 'RFCacc', 'RFCsens', 'RFCspec', 'RFCprec', 'RFCFscore', 'RFCAUC-ROC'
                                    'SVMacc', 'SVMsens', 'SVMspec', 'SVMprec', 'SVMFscore', 'SVMAUC-ROC'])
thresholds = [0.75]
cs = [1]
class_weights = [{'Control':1, 'SCD':1}, #'MCI':1}, 
                {'Control':1.75, 'SCD':1.5}, #'MCI':1}, 
                {'Control':2, 'SCD':1.75} #'MCI':1}
                ]

#this is the loop used to iterate through param combintions
for threshold in thresholds:
    for c in cs:
        for class_weight in class_weights:
            row = {}
            svmAcc = []
            rfAcc = []
            X=dfClass
            y=df_classification.loc[df_classification['Diagnosis'].isin(['Control', 'SCD'])]
            loo = LeaveOneOut()
            loo.get_n_splits(dfClass)
            # let's count the selected features in a Counter
            featCount = Counter()
            # the LOOCV happens here with the selected parameter combination
            for train_index, test_index in loo.split(dfClass):
                X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
                y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
                pvalue = []
                x_control = X_train.loc[y_train=='Control', :].astype('float64', copy=False)
                x_scd = X_train.loc[y_train=='SCD', :].astype('float64', copy=False)
```

When I do this, I come across this error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_list_axis(self, key, axis)
   1529         try:
-> 1530             return self.obj._take_with_is_copy(key, axis=axis)
   1531         except IndexError as err:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _take_with_is_copy(self, indices, axis)
   3627         """
-> 3628         result = self.take(indices=indices, axis=axis)
   3629         # Maybe set copy if we didn't actually change the index.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in take(self, indices, axis, is_copy, **kwargs)
   3615         new_data = self._mgr.take(
-> 3616             indices, axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis), verify=True
   3617         )

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in take(self, indexer, axis, verify)
    861         n = self.shape[axis]
--> 862         indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n, verify=verify)
    863 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexers.py in maybe_convert_indices(indices, n, verify)
    291         if mask.any():
--> 292             raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")
    293     return indices

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-7df8494e8241> in <module>
     27             for train_index, test_index in loo.split(dfClass):
     28                 X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
---> 29                 y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
     30                 pvalue = []
     31                 x_control = X_train.loc[y_train=='Control', :].astype('float64', copy=False)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    929 
    930             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 931             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    932 
    933     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1555         # a list of integers
   1556         elif is_list_like_indexer(key):
-> 1557             return self._get_list_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1558 
   1559         # a single integer

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_list_axis(self, key, axis)
   1531         except IndexError as err:
   1532             # re-raise with different error message
-> 1533             raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds") from err
   1534 
   1535     def _getitem_axis(self, key, axis: int):

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

This error may be because I'm using .loc and then .iloc, but is there a way around it? I want only certain parts of my dataframe as "y" for the classification. What else am I doing wrong here?